# How do i get the value of the checked radio button given the id of the div they are wrapped in?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="q3-slider" class="sliderClass">
                <input type="radio" name="like-amount" id="3-1" value="1" required>
                <label for="3-1" data-like-amount="Ew!"></label>
                <input type="radio" name="like-amount" id="3-2" value="2" required>
                <label for="3-2" data-like-amount="Meh"></label>
                <input type="radio" name="like-amount" id="3-3" value="3" required>
                <label for="3-3" data-like-amount="okay.."></label>
                <input type="radio" name="like-amount" id="3-4" value="4" required>
                <label for="3-4" data-like-amount="A bit"></label>
                <input type="radio" name="like-amount" id="3-5" value="5" required>
                <label for="3-5" data-like-amount="A lot"></label>
            </div>
```

I want to find the value of the check radio button insider this div which has an id of q3-slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a way to do it

```
rbs = document.querySelectorAll(`#q3-slider input[name="like-amount"]`);
    let selectedValue
    for (const rb of rbs) {
        if (rb.checked) {
            selectedValue = rb.value;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can get the checked item's value as follows,

    var parent = $('input[name="like-amount"]:checked').parent().attr('id');
            if (parent == 'q3-slider'){
                var radio = $('input[name="like-amount"]:checked').val();
            }
```

Comment: The main problem I am facing is that I have more divs with different ids that have radio button groups with the same name.

Comment: I think you can use .parent() for that. for more information follow https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_parent.asp

Comment: @RahulChatterjee now see my answer. it getting value for radio that related to div you have specified.